# How to store objects at two different indexes of one NSArray to one index of another NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` mentioned below.
a{
some objects
}
b{
some objects
}
c{
some objects
}

I would like to know if there is any way to store a,b index into one index in another `NSArray` ?

Comment: Could you provide a small example of a, b and the expected output (c)?

Comment: Just to clarify, a, b, c placed at indexes 0, 1, 2. Do you want to store a and b objects into the another array at index 0?

Comment: @Sandeep Maganti I guess you want to combine results of two different array into one array?

Comment: {
        20620802 =         {
                    };
    },
        {
        20624642 =         {
        };
    },
        {
        20623874 =         {
            
        };
Suppose there are the objects at indexes 0,1,2 in the array name testArray i want to know is it possible to have indexes 0,1 in the same index for testArray1.

Comment: i mean object at index 0 of testArray1 should contain indexes 0,1 of testArray. is it possible ?

Comment: exactly @DenFav

Comment: @Sandeep Maganti Well I guess no not possible may be someone else have an idea.If you want multiple values at one index you can create array of dictionary objects for that.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` in which you wants to add element and then 
Put both object form other array In a `NSMutableDictionary` for particular  keys and then add `NSMutableDictionary` to object desired `index` in `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find these two object add them to the new NSArray(it will have 2 objects inside) and add this array to an another array at index 0 as you want